# Create a variable from a html selector and then check for items within it

Tags: jquery, html

I create a variable from a html object

```
var li = $(this).closest('li');
```

How do I now select inner html objects from this variable eg span.
I have tried

```
li.span
```

but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use context to pass the variable with selector. You can learn more about selector and context [**here**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)

```
var li = $(this).closest('li');
$('span', li)
htmlOfFirstSpan = $('span', li).html();
```

*This will give you span elements within li*

Comment: Thanks @WesleySkeen, same for you.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var li = $(this).closest('li');
$(li).innerHtml();
```

You could also do:

```
$(li).('span').html();
$(li).('.someClass').html();
```